# Subtracting two layers in MapInfo?

Tags: layers, mapinfo

I have two tables, one is a cartographic map and the other is the map of all lakes. Some of the lakes are in-land and so they are not excluded from the cartographic map.

I want to calculate the area of each, say city (object of land map), subtracting the area for rivers, lakes etc. (object of the water map).

Is it possible to do in MapInfo?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you want to do. Is the city an object type in your "cartographic map" table? And if yes, do you want the area of these objects but extracting the area where they overlap features in your "map of lakes" table?

Answer (score 2):

You can get your area of overlap using a selection. Let's assume you have 2 tables, `land` and `water`. Using Query > SQL Select you can query the area of overlap between intersecting objects:

```sql
Select land.ID, water.ID, AreaOverlap(land.obj, water.obj) "Overlap" 
From land, water 
Where land.obj intersects water.obj 
Into ObjectOverlap
```

Depending on the size of your tables this may take a while. You may want to query out only the intersecting objects before you run the above query to try and speed things up.

You can now update a new column (e.g. `Overlap`) in your `land` table with the overlap area from the `ObjectOverlap` table where the `land.ID` fields match.

Then add a column for the subtracted area and update it with:

```
Area(land.obj) - land.Overlap
```

Make sure you've got your units set correctly (under options) before you start.